# Does exist a real numbered sequence with a "countable number of limits"?

Tags: real-analysis

Does exist a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in the real numbers such that for every element $l$ in a infinite countable set $L$ there is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ that converges to $l$?
$ $

(context):
I really do not have much context about this. I just wanted to know if there existed such sequence and couldn't come up with an answer by my own.

Comment: Enumerate the rationals, and every real number is the limit of some subsequence

Comment: This was amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for each of your countably many limits you have a sequence converging to that limit, you can construct $\{a_n\}$ in the form of a [triangular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_array)
$$\begin{array}{cccc} a_1 \\ a_2 & a_3 \\ a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots \end{array}$$
by populating each column with each of your sequences.

Comment: Great. I did not knew about this kind of constructions. Thanks